# Laravel 5 - setting up relationships

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I have been struggling a little with my application and asked a lot of questions, and before I go any further, I just want to make sure that my relationships are ok.

So I am creating an application whereby you can generate different documents based on the input you provide.  So, I create a project, and within that project there is a select field which has different types of documents.  If I select DocumentA for example, the create form for DocumentA will be displayed to the user.  If I choose DocumentB, the create form for DocumentB will be displayed.  Now although these forms are different and take different inputs, I wanted a way whereby I would not have to create a new table for every document type.  So I came up with the following.

[image: Design]

So within a project, I select I want to create DocumentA.  I am then displayed the view documentA.create.  This view has hidden inputs for the document name and description.  The form fields labels are the key in the document_data table, and the value is the input for this field.  So, if I create DocumentA, my database might look like this

```
project

 id | projectName  | 
------------------
 1  | Project One  | 
------------------

document

 id | projectId  | documentName |
--------------------------------
 1  | 1          | DocumentA    |
--------------------------------


document_data

 id | documentId | key         |  value      |  
----------------------------------------------
 1  | 1          | clientName  |  Google     |   
----------------------------------------------
 2  | 1          | projectName |  Analytics  |  
----------------------------------------------
 3  | 1          | Contact     |  Mr Sharp   |  
----------------------------------------------
 4  | 1          | startDate   |  29/12/2016 |  
----------------------------------------------
```

Where I am struggling at the moment is that the foreign key documentId is in the document_data table.  However, things are only working if I set a foreign key in both of my Models classes e.g.

```
class Document extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'documents';
    protected $guarded = [];

    public function documentData()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\DocumentData', 'documentId');
    }
}

class DocumentData extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'document_data';
    protected $guarded = [];

    public function document()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Document', 'documentId');
    }
}
```

If I dont set it in both classes, I get a MethodNotAllowedHTTP exception with no information about it.  I have been able to create documents without problem, the problem comes when I need to update.  The edit page for DocumentA has a form starting like this

```
{{ $document }}

{!! Form::model($project->document, [
    'class'=>'form-horizontal',
    'method' => 'PATCH',
    'route' => ['projects.documents.update', $project, $project->document]
]) !!}
```

Now when I output $document above, I get the correct document that I am working on, as I should do.  However, in the update function, if I output $document on its own or if I do

```
public function update(Request $request, Project $project, Document $document)
{
    dd($project->document);

    return null;
}
```

I see both DocumentA and DocumentB.  Shouldnt the update only be passed DocumentA?

Why would this be?  Any information or advice hugely appreciated.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is the relationship between project and document. You probably have document belongsTo project, and project hasMany document, as you can have many documents with projectId = 1. Isn't it?
It what I said is okay, when you write $project->document, it brings you all the documents that belong to that project. It's confusing because you named the relationship 'document' instead of 'documents'. 
You can do 2 things:
1- If each project can have only 1 document, change the relationship in the 'Project' model to hasOne Document. Then, if you do $project->document it will bring you only one.
2- If your app allows a project to have multiple documents, leave the relationship as hasMany (I'd recommend to rename it to documents instead of document), and pass the $document object to the update form, instead of passing the $project and trying to access the document from there.
Please let me know if I missed the point of your question and I'm totally wrong

Comment: Hi, thank you for your input.  A Project can have many Document, so I should rename it to Documents.  At the moment, my edit view has the correct document.  If I pass this document object via the form though, when I output Document within my controller, it seems to be an empty Object.  Do you know why this might be the case?

Comment: Can I see your route for the update method? I've had issues with passing dynamic parameters to post/patch routes in laravel (personal experience), so I'd modify two things to your code. In the form, write {!! Form::model($document, [ 'etc' ]) !!} instead of $project->document/s (in case you renamed the relationship). Remove the dynamic parameters in the patch route. If you need to pass the project to the controller, pass it's id as a hidden variable in the form. Your route in the form should now be 'route' => 'projects.documents.update' . In the controller write dd($request->input());

Comment: So, sorry to be insistent. I want you to see the mistake in your form. What would you write if you needed to update the second document of the project? $project->document wouldn't work either. That's why you should give it the specific $document. $project->document returns a collection, not a Document instance

Comment: Hi, I have actually found a solution now.  The form passes the id of the document I am working on, and then I use this to get the correct document within my controller.  Seems to work.  Thanks